# Requests from Uploadify 3.1 in Rails 3.2.2 with Authlogic don't yield a current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, uploadify, authlogic

I'm using Uploadify 3.1 with Rails 3.2.2. I use Authlogic to deal with authentication. Authlogic provides a `current_user` method which gives the user which made the request.

When I try to upload some file with Uploadify 3.1, current_user is not set when looked for in an action, it gives `nil`. This did not happen with the Uploadify 2.1.4. Here is how I'm calling uploadify:

```
jQuery('#something').uploadify({

      uploader        : '#{some_path_from_rails_routes}',
      swf             : '/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
      cancelImg       : '/uploadify/cancel.png',
      fileTypeDesc    : 'FileNames',
      auto            : true,
      removeCompleted : false,
      buttonText      : 'Some Label',
      formData        : {
        '_http_accept': 'application/javascript',
        '#{session_key_name}' : encodeURIComponent('#{u(cookies[session_key_name])}'),
        'authenticity_token'  : encodeURIComponent('#{u(form_authenticity_token)}'),
      }
});
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Uploadify's flash component uses a different cookie storage than the one Rails uses for its sessions. You can use the [flash_cookie_session](https://github.com/trevorturk/flash_cookie_session) gem to work around this problem.

From its documentation, it looks like you will need to modify your `formData` to something like this:

```
{
  "<%= key = Rails.application.config.session_options[:key] %>" : "<%= cookies[key] %>"
  "<%= request_forgery_protection_token %>" : "<%= form_authenticity_token %>",
}
```

Comment: This is now built into the uploadify-rails gem, as of version 3.1.1.1.  Just include flash_cookie_session in your Gemfile before uploadify-rails and it will handle everything for you behind the scenes.

Comment: @IsaacBetesh which uploadify-rails gem?  This one seems to be a near empty shell that hasn't been uploaded for 2 years - https://github.com/nragaz/uploadify-rails

Comment: Filip Tepper's: https://github.com/filiptepper/uploadify-rails (this is the one you'll find on rubygems.org)